# AEM Solr integration: Remote Solr as an oak Index issue: "undefined field catch_all"

Tags: solr, aem, solr4, aem-6

I have integrated AEM with remote Solr as, 'Solr as an Oak index' and when running solr queries, I could see all my content indexed and shown into remote Solr.

However when I run some AEM specific jcr queries in AEM for certain search application, In the AEM logs, I could see the request going through to solr to fetch content but the result is empty. In Solr logs following is the stack trace:

```
2019-02-26 13:09:56.093 ERROR (qtp1514322932-145) [ x:oak] o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field catch_all
  at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1300)
  at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1252)
  at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getWildcardQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:772)
  at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:508)
  at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:309)
  at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:180)
  at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:101)
  at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:90)
  at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:152)
  at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:50)
  at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:140)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Also, what is the official version of Solr which is supported on these types on integrations?

P.S: I have deleted the default oak index and I am just using the new solr oak index, which is when I am facing this issue.

Comment: Is the search field "catch_all" defined in your Solr schema?

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Answer (score 1):

From **Solr** log, it is obvious there are some problems with getting **catch_all** field that either doesn't exist or is not defined properly (check on field type as well).

- To be albe to index data, you should create a document.
- Documents consists of a fields.
- Field has it's type and attributes.
- The field type defines how Solr interprets data in a field and how the field can be queried.

Check that you have everything mentioned above defined properly.

More about field types:
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/field-type-definitions-and-properties.html#field-type-definitions-and-properties

More about Solr as an Oak index:
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/eseminars/gems/Solr-as-an-Oak-index-for-AEM1.html#main-pars_multi_column